# How can I create a specific heat map?

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, heatmap

Which language or website can I use as a tutorial to create heat maps? I want to customize my own heat map (e.g give it for example a map (such as a house top view) and use heat map on it, not specifically an actual world map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `javascript` you can create heatmap using [heatmap.js](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/).

One example is on `codepen` - this time just js and html canvas - [link](https://codepen.io/MattRyder/pen/Fvunk).

That's what I've found. Good luck!